# Command \ifcsname not expanding correctly when used in macro

Tags: macros, conditionals

For practical reasons I want to substitute the somewhat verbose

```
\ifcsname some_variable\endcsname
\fi
```

by a combination of

```
\def\customif#1{\ifcsname #1\endcsname}

\customif{some_variable}
\fi
```

The first works as expected even if some_variable is undefined, while the `\customif` approach yields a somewhat unexpected result.

I know that I must be missing something, but I can not figure out why the following code fails to compile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\customif#1{\ifcsname #1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
    \expandafter\def\csname some_variable\endcsname{}

    \ifcsname some_variable\endcsname
        This works.
    \fi

    \customif{some_variable}
        So does this.
    \fi

    \ifcsname other_variable\endcsname
        \ifcsname other_variable\endcsname
            This compiles and does not print (as expected).
        \fi
    \fi

    \customif{other_variable}
        This also compiles and does not print.
    \fi

    \customif{other_variable}
        \customif{other_variable}
            This fails.
        \fi
    \fi

    \customif{other_variable}
    \else
        \customif{other_variable}
        \else
            On the other hand, this compiles and prints.
        \fi
    \fi
\end{document}
```

Compiling with pdflatex I get

```
! Extra \fi.
l.30     \fi
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example

```
\customif{other_variable}
    \customif{other_variable}
        This fails.
    \fi
\fi
```

the inner `\customif` is not expanded, so the `\ifcsname` in its replacement text is not seen. So the first `\fi` is paired with the `\ifcsname` resulting from the expansion of the outer `\customif` and the next one is dangling alone.

More detailed: the code, after expansion of `\customif{other_variable}` becomes

```
\ifcsname other_variable\endcsname
    \customif{other_variable}
        This fails.
    \fi
\fi
```

The test returns false, so everything up to the *first* `\fi` is skipped over.

You can do it in a different way:

```
\def\custom#1{TT\fi\ifcsname #1\endcsname}
```

and then call it as

```
\if\custom{some_variable}
  <true text>
\else
  <false text>
\fi
```

which will work also nested because of the `\if`. (Don't forget to protect the line endings when necessary.)

---

If you're worried about a dangling initial `\fi` (that will however disappear immediately upon expansion) you can do

```
\def\custom#1{T\expandafter X\expandafter X\fi\ifcsname #1\endcsname}
```

---

A different approach is to use “braced branches”:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\vardefTF[1]{%
  \ifcsname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

to be called like

```
\vardefTF{some_var}{True}{False}
```

This has the disadvantage that the true and false branches are read in as arguments, but has less problems when nested.

With `expl3` this is predefined, so

```
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \vardefTF \cs_if_exist:cTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

would provide `\vardefTF` behaving like before.

---

A different idea, suggested by Bruno Le Floch:

```
\def\custom#1{%
  T\ifcsname#1\endcsname
  \expandafter T\else\expandafter F\fi
}
```

If the code

```
\if\custom{some_variable}<True>\else<False>\fi
```

is inside a skipped conditional branch, the `\if` will be balanced by `\else` (optional as usual) and `\fi`. On the other hand, when `\if` is not skipped and expanded, when `\ifcsname` returns true, `\if` will find `TT`, otherwise it will find `TF`, choosing accordingly the following branches.

This has the advantage that one can prefix `\if` with `\unless`.

(The old `TT\fi` trick was born before `\unless` became available.)

Comment: Great answer, thank you! What exactly does TT\fi stand for?

Comment: @jcmonteiro When `\if\custom{...}` is expanded, `\if TT\fi` disappears and only `\ifcsname ...\endcsname` remains; when unexpanded, the `\if` serves to balance `\else` and `\fi`.

Comment: I’d also suggest switching to LaTeX-style conditional, _e.g._, `\newcommand*{\ifcustom}[1]{\ifcsname #1\endcsname \expandafter\@firstoftwo \else \expandafter\@secondoftwo \fi}`.  Why don’t you add this to your answer?

Comment: There is something wrong in your middle example. Maybe `\def\custom#1{\fi \ifcsname#1\endcsname}` is sufficient (without any `\expandafter` and without any `TXX`).

Comment: @wipet Remember about the “frozen `\relax`”; with just `\fi` instead of `TT\fi` two `\relax` tokens would be inserted, which are unwanted in a full expansion context.

Comment: May be misunderstanding. Please think about your middle example in detail. Is it really OK? There is no redundant `\expandafter`s? And what about the `\if` inside `\custom` macro?

Comment: @wipet Yes, of course it was wrong! Thanks for noting.

Comment: @wipet The first `\expandafter` could be removed; it doesn't harm, does it?

Comment: Instead of your `\custom` I would use `\def\custom#1{T\ifcsname #1\endcsname\expandafter T\else\expandafter F\fi}` to avoid the leading `\fi` completely and deal with cases such as `\unless\if\custom{...}...\fi`.  The other advantage is that expanding the `\if` once will correctly perform the test rather than leaving some `\fi` and `\ifcsname` around.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch very nice idea

Answer (score 7):

I am using different approach than `TT` for such situations. I define `\is...` macro which realizes the test and it has one more parameter than is really needed. This (ignored) parameter is `\iftrue` when the macro is used. Our example looks like:

```
\def\isdefined#1#2{\ifcsname #1\endcsname}
```

and usage:

```
\isdefined{some_text}\iftrue
   <true text>
\else
   <false text>
\fi
```

Note that you need not to put `%` at the end of the first line.

Comment: Interesting approach, but, IMHO, less readabe than that presented in @egreg’s answer.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti But `\cs_set_eq:NN \vardefTF \cs_if_exist:cTF` (in egreg's answer) is generally unreadable.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti and wipet: readability is *so* much about what you're used to, what you've worked with, and personal preference :) IMHO for example texts in Chinese are generally unreadable but I bet Chinese people will beg to differ… ;)

Comment: `\if\isdefined{some_text}...\fi` has the slight advantage of expanding in one step, provided we define `\def\isdefined#1{T\expandafter\expandafter\ifcsname #1\endcsname T\else F\fi}`.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use a LaTeX-style conditional.  For example, in the code below we define a command `\CustomIfDef`, with should be used as follows

```
\CustomIfDef{<cs-name>}{<if-defined-code>}{<if-undefined-code>}
```

and can be nested without problems.  Note, however, that in case of nesting it is less efficient than @egreg approach, because the code for the various cases needs to be copied between the levels as an argument.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\CustomIfDef[1]{%
    \ifcsname #1\endcsname
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\newcommand*\CustomDefEmpty[1]{\@namedef{#1}{}}

\makeatother

\nofiles



\begin{document}

\CustomDefEmpty{Foo_bar_123.$}

\CustomIfDef{Pluto!}{
    \typeout{==> Outer branch true.}
}{
    \typeout{==> Outer branch false.}
    \CustomIfDef{Foo_bar_123.$}{
        \typeout{----> Mid-level branch true.}
        \CustomIfDef{relax}{
            \typeout{......> Inner branch: \relax is defined.}
        }{
            \typeout{......> Inner branch: \relax is NOT defined.}
        }
    }{
        \typeout{----> Mid-level branch false.}
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Plus one for the `\typeout` command which I didn't know about!